# setting `PYTHONWARNINGS` to disable python warnings seems to do nothing

Tags: python, executable, suppress-warnings, deprecation-warning

I'm currently running the `openstack` executable and it generates python deprecation warnings.

After some searching I did find [this](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/suppress-warnings-python/#use-the-pythonwarnings-environment-variable-to-suppress-warnings-in-python) howto.

The [relevant part](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/suppress-warnings-python/#use-the-pythonwarnings-environment-variable-to-suppress-warnings-in-python) is here:

> ### Use the `PYTHONWARNINGS` Environment Variable to Suppress Warnings in Python
>
> We can export a new environment variable in Python 2.7 and up. We can export `PYTHONWARNINGS` and set it to ignore to suppress the warnings raised in the Python program.

However, doing this:

```sh
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore" openstack image show image name -f value -c id
```

does nothing, deprecation warnings are still displayed.

I've tried setting `PYTHONWARNINGS` to various things:

- `ignore`
- `"ignore"`
- `"all"`
- `"deprecated"`
- `"ignore::DeprecationWarning"`
- `"error::Warning,default::Warning:has_deprecated_syntax"`
- `"error::Warning"`

but none of them seem to do anything.

I was able to work around the issue by appending `2>/dev/null` to the end but I would like to know why `PYTHONWARNINGS` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PYTHONWARNINGS` certainly does suppress python's warnings.  Try running:

```sh
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore" python -c "import warnings; warnings.warn('hi')"
```

But in this case you are not calling python, but openstack, which is apparently not inheriting the same environment.  Without looking at the source I can't say why.  It may even be explicitly settings the warning level, which will override anything you do before hand.

If you don't want to see errors, sending STDERR to `/dev/null` is the proper approach.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly need to "export PYTHONWARNINGS" so it is avaialble to anything openstack invokes

Answer (score 0):

For me the following command suppers the deprecation warning and I am not getting the warning any more.

$ export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore::UserWarning"